# How can I use Win+Shift+Alt as a hotkey in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I want to activate a script with the key combination <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. How would I do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
Space::
    Run, App

#Persistent
SetTimer, PressTheKey1, 500
SetTimer, PressTheKey2, 0

PressTheKey1:
    Send, {click}
Return

PressTheKey2:
    Send, {t}
Return

Escape::
    ExitApp
Return
```

Comment: I don't think that its possible to only use the Win, Shift, and Alt keys alone to trigger a script. Win, Shift, and Alt are all considered to be `Modifiers` which means that they need to be paired with a `Hotkey` to take effect. Some examples of `Hotkeys` would be: regular letter keys on the keyboard, numbers on the Numpad, F1 thru F12 keys, Enter, Space

Comment: ok so what would be the code if i wanted to win-shift-4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `Win`, `Shift`, and  `4` combo as a `Hotkey`:

```
#+4::
    ; Your script here
```

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't trigger the script.

Comment: What section of the script do you want that hotkey to activate?

Comment: what do you mean by section?

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest script?

Comment: I don't believe you can have the `#Persistent` line in the same script that outlines hotkeys. You will likely have to break the `#Persistent` section out into its own script and run both simultaneously.